# Laravel installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

No existing questions are sufficiently basic to answer my problem. I am trying to install Laravel to try it out and have successfully installed Composer but all advice about installing Laravel itself seems to involve something called Git and a 'terminal' which I know nothing about. Can I not simply download a setup file and run it as for other apps?

Mike

Comment: Are you trolling? How can someone work in this area and not know what git or a terminal is?

Comment: That's the good thing about Laravel. It makes you do things the better way. As linked by handsome Antonio you can get a zip file of the framework boilerplate and install the dependencies through composer.

Comment: I'm a 72-year-old engineer - I love web development but sometimes have trouble keeping up. I rely on you younger guys having some patience. I've used Codeigniter for half-a-dozen sites but it didn't involve Git. I thought I'd give Laravel a try :)

Comment: Yes, there is such an option you can try Laragon http://laragon.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Laravel Framework in Windows:

Created By : Chirag Shah

PHP version greater than 5.3.7 is required

**Step 1**:  Download Laravel from: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip

**Step 2**:  Extract Laravel into the www folder for WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com)

**Step 3**:  Download Composer from: https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

**Step 4**:  Install Composer into the same directory php.exe is located

**Step 5**:  Click on WAMP icon->PHP->PHP Extensions and enable: php_openssl, php_curl, php_socket

**Step 6**:  Click on wamp icon->Apache->Apache Modules and enable ssl_module

**Step 7**:  Enable openssl from all php.ini files

**Step 8**:  Open cmd

**Step 9**:  Change into the directory where you extracted Laravel e.g: cd C:\wamp\www\laravel

**Step 10**: Type the command: composer install

**step 11**: Copy and paste all \public\ folder files into WAMP's www folder

**Step 12**: Open bootstrap\paths.php and edit the line 'public' => **DIR**.'/../public', to 'public' => **DIR**.'/../www',

Installation completed.

Enjoy....

Comment: Many thanks for this reply. In the time between asking the question and now, I had in fact found out how to do all this by trial and error and other sources. How I wish I had had your guide at the outset and how many hours it would have saved me. I hope it will now help other noobs who search this forum. Bless you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, this is the link to the zip file:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip

But at some point you might need Git, so you better get along with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry to let you know that laravel at some point requires you to handle a terminal. Git is not a necessary attribute for just a try out. Terminal is nothing to be scared of - its actually the command line which is referred to as the terminal.

You can get a lot of tutorials and help on how to use terminal effectively. And using the terminal solves you a lot of trouble too. If you are interested in learning and programming in laravel take an interest in studying the terminal too.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to install 5.1 laravel in windows using wamp or xampp:**

-> Step 1: install **`laravel`** composer (you can download it from https://getcomposer.org/)

-> Step 2: open command prompt then download and install **`laravel`** installer using composer by the following command:

**`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`**

-> Step 3: Right click on my computer then go advanced tab then environment variables and in system variable search for **`path`** -> and put the following code in the end of line after ;(semicolon) :

**`;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;`**

-> Step 4: then go to **`wamp`** directory ie: **`e:wamp/www/`** (i have installed **`wamp`**  in E directory)

-> Step 5: open command prompt and select the current directory using following commands:
**1. e:
2. `cd www/laravel`**

-> Step 6: in command prompt run follow command:
**`laravel new blog`**

Now **`laravel`**  project with name **`blog`** is installed on your local machine using **`wamp`** or **`xampp`**.

open **`http://localhost/laravel/blog/public`** in your browser.

on success you will see **`laravel 5`** logo.

**Enjoy with laravel installation.**