# How to rewrite or remove /public from Laravel URLs

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to remove the `public/index` from laravel url, since this is one of the common question so there are lot of tutorials and answer. I also searched about this and followed this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735930) which is working fine for me it's pretty simple.

> Rename the server.php in the your Laravel root folder to index.php and copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder. -- Thats it !! :)

I'm confuse why i should rename or move something from one place to another because there will be a reason why files exist in public folder.

I'm thinking that by following above answer's step may be create some issues in future if there will be a new requirement or new feature request in the project.

So can anyone guide me is there any best to rewrite or remove the `public/index` from laravel 5. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me.

Comment: can you check these steps once - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884947/laravel-installation/18908991#18908991 note sure whether it would help you but just wanted to share with you if you can look at it once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should configure your web server's document / web root to be the `public` directory. That way you don't have to copy/move/delete anything.

For `apache` you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891858/1561146).

For `nginx` you can read [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx).

Answer (score 1):

I've visited your link and saw really terrible advices.

You do no need to move any Laravel files or modify them. What you need is to setup web server. You need to point it to a `public` directory which is inside Laravel project root folder.

Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) for an example config directives for Apache and nginx.

Answer (score -1):

One other option is to symlink the `public` folder to your server's root folder (e.g. `/var/www/`). [This article](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) is a great guide on how to do this.

On your dev environment however you can use `php artisan serve`.

Comment: That's a terrible answer. OP should configure the webserver properly to serve from the public laravel folder.

Answer (score -1):

Remove public from url without htaccess. It will work on laravel latest versions also.

step 1. Copy all files from public and paste on root directory

step 2. Open index.php file remove ../ from path as given below

Laravel5:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Laravel 7:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```